# how to ignore negative numbers

Tags: text-processing, awk

let's consider the following example

```
1 4.0 3.5 7.2
2 3.2 2.5 5.2
3 1.7 -1.8 2.9
4 4.1 2.5 5.7
```

How can I extract the 3rd column of the table by ignoring the negative number?

If I use `awk '{print $3}' filename`, it will give me all the four numbers. But I want to take only positive numbers, i.e. the final output must be three numbers:

```
3.5
2.5
2.5
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the input is purely numeric, as shown in the question:

```bsh
awk '$3 >= 0 { print $3 }' file
```

The test in front of the block determines whether the block will run.  In this case, the test is an arithmetic test which will be *true* if the data in the 3rd field is a non-negative number.  When this is the case, that field is outputted.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to treat the third column either as a number or as a string. `awk` has implicit conversion from string to number if the context requires it, with non-numeric values equated to zero and non-numeric suffixes being ignored.

In this solution there is no numeric comparison. The string is checked to see that it does not begin with a minus symbol, `-`, and is output only if so:

```
awk '$3 !~ /^-/ {print $3}' filename
```

(This solution will skip the value if it begins with `-` even if it is not a negative number. For example `--00`. Modifying the RE or forcing a numeric comparison may address that. If you have only numeric values then this issue will not arise.)

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '$3 ~/^[0-9]/{print $3}' file.txt
```

output

```
3.5
2.5
2.5
```